# md5 encryption qwerty - azerty error

Tags: php, md5

For my php-login system combined with a MySQL database, I use a md5 - encryption to convert passwords when an user registers himself. Everything worked fine on a Windows-host,
but now I've changed the host to Linux.
Now, when I register a example user, with password "azerty", I couldn't login...
When I trie to login with "qwerty" as password, it works.
So it's like the md5 function read my keyboard as a qwerty keyboard instead as an azerty...

What can I do to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

In the register script I do this:

```
$password = md5($password);
```

and then save `$password` to my database.

The loginscript checks on this:

```
if ($username == $dbusername && md5($password) == $dbpassword)
```

Comment: Is this a hypothetical problem? There's no such thing as MD5 encryption.

Comment: Please show some example debug outputs. What does the password field actually contain before you MD5 it? Also show some code

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just type the password in correctly? `Q` and `A` are pretty close to one another.

Comment: Please show some example debug outputs. What does the password field actually contain before you MD5 it?

Comment: A 'q' is a 'q' and an 'a' is an 'a' no matter where it shows up on a keyboard. Rearranging my keys to turn my keyboard into a dvorak layout doesn't invalidate all my passwords just because I moved the plastic caps around.

Comment: Going off what @todda.speot.is said, MD5 is a hash algorithm. Basically hashs are 1 way and can't be reversed, that doesn't mean you can't beat them though - check out the article Incognito gave you, and encryption is 2 ways - you can encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: Somebody's going around down-voting a bunch of Q&As. >:-(

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t matter that you switched hosts. If you can *log in* with “querty” then you must have inadvertently *registered* with “querty”

When you’re **testing** the system, use a normal `<input type="text">` so you can *see* what you’re typing. Switch it `<input type="password">` when you’re finished testing. Also, add a “verify password” field so you can verify that the user didn’t accidentally mistype her password.

### Secure Password Storage Primer

Add a field to your users table called "salt"

In the register script do this:

```php
$salt = time();
$code = hash('sha256', $password . $salt);
```

Save `$code` and `$salt` in the users table.

In the loginscript check this:

```php
if ($username === $dbusername && hash('sha256', $password . $dbsalt) === $dbpassword)
```

Comment: @John: Thanks. It's been happening a lot lately to a lot of other people.